# В чем проблема? Python. vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

бот для вк на питоне через vk_api в пайчарме.
вот сам код. токен вырезал по очевидным причинам:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkChatEventType
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="")
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpool = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def send_some_msg(id, some_text):
    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id":id, "message":some_text,"random_id":0})
    for event in longpool.listen():
        if event.type == VkChatEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.to_me:
                msg = event.text.lower()
                id = event.user_id
                if msg == "hi":
                    send_some_msg(id,"gg")
```

и ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Win/PycharmProjects/пончик/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    vk_session = vk_api(token = "")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

я новичок, так что , если тут что-то элементарное, не бейте.
заранее спасибо <3

Comment: Показанный вами код явно не соответствует коду в тексте ошибки

Comment: Код в вопросе и код в ошибке не совпадают. В ошибке вы пытаетесь вызвать модуль vk_api как функцию: `vk_session = vk_api(token = "")`. Так нельзя делать, поэтому вылетает ошибка (в ошибке так и написано, что объект модуль не callable - т.е. не "вызываемый"). В коде выше у вас написано правильно, берется класс из модуля, и создается объект, ошибки быть не должно: `vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="")`

Answer (score 0):

У тебя ошибка в строке, где ты вырезал токен, следовательно, токен вставишь, ошибка пропадет.

Comment: Не "следовательно". В ошибке ни слова про токен, в ошибке написано, что модуль vk_api не вызываемый.